# PHP: preg_replace with unique replacement

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace each instance of a given string with a number.

ex:

```
<?php

$string = "Hello Foo Text Apple"
preg_replace($pattern, $pattern.$i++, $string);

//output    
Hello0 Foo1 Text2 Apple3

?>
```

the *$pattern* is a regex query but in this case I have used plain text

Comment: You want to replace or append the number?

Comment: @jwerre: I want to append a number/string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "Hello Hello Hello Test Hello Test";

$i = 0;
$string = preg_replace("/\w+/e", '$0 . $i++', $string);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the increments must not stop. eg. Hello1 Test2 Something3

Comment: @dany: Updated code. Set `$i` to what you want the count to start at.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP 5.3:

```
$string = "Hello Hello Hello Hello";
$i = 0;
preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) use ($i) {
    return $matches[0].$i++;
}, $string);
```